# Deserialize Json String Type Not known

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization

I have JSON as below:

```
   {
 "request" :
 {
  "command" : "series",
  "series_id" : "PET.WCRSTUS1.W"
 },
 "series" : [
  {
   "series_id" : "PET.WCRSTUS1.W",
   "name" : "U.S. Ending Stocks of Crude Oil, Weekly",
   "units" : "Thousand Barrels",
   "f" : "W",
   "unitsshort" : "Mbbl",
   "description" : "U.S. Ending Stocks of Crude Oil",
   "copyright" : "None",
   "source" : "EIA, U.S. Energy Information Administration",
   "iso3166" : "USA",
   "geography" : "USA",
   "start" : "19820820",
   "end" : "20160715",
   "updated" : "2016-07-20T13:18:37-0400",
   "data" : [["20160715", 1214561], 
   ["20160708", 1216904], 
   ["20160701", 1219452], 
   ["20160624", 1221677], 
   ["20160617", 1225730], 
   ["20160610", 1226647], 
   ["20160603", 1227580]]
  }
 ]
}
```

I have used an online JSON convertor to generate C# as below:

```
public class Request
{
    public string command { get; set; }
    public string series_id { get; set; }
}

public class Series
{
    public string series_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string units { get; set; }
    public string f { get; set; }
    public string unitsshort { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string copyright { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
    public string iso3166 { get; set; }
    public string geography { get; set; }
    public string start { get; set; }
    public string end { get; set; }
    public string updated { get; set; }
    public List<List<Object>> data { get; set; }
}


public class RootObject
{
    public Request request { get; set; }
    public List<Series> series { get; set; }
}
```

Now, note that the 'data' property of 'Series' is a List of List.  What I would like to do is create a class to represent these:

```
public class DataItem
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

And then amend the Series class as below:

```
public class Series
{
    public string series_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string units { get; set; }
    public string f { get; set; }
    public string unitsshort { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string copyright { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
    public string iso3166 { get; set; }
    public string geography { get; set; }
    public string start { get; set; }
    public string end { get; set; }
    public string updated { get; set; }
    public List<DataItem> data { get; set; }
}
```

When I do this, I get the correct number of items in the data property but each individual DataItem has default values (null string and 0 for value).  Please can someone suggest how (if) this can be achieved.

My deserialization is using System.Runtime.Serialization (not Json.Net). The deserialization routine can be considered as out of my control for this purpose. Not sure if this is relevant but snippet below:

```
    public static T FromJsonString<T>(string json, Type[] extraTypes = null)
    {
        T result;
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T), extraTypes ?? new Type[] { });

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
            {
                writer.Write(json);
                writer.Flush();
                stream.Position = 0;
                result = (T) serializer.ReadObject(stream);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

So to summarise:

- How do I get the list of data objects to be deserialized to my DataItem class?  The type is not denoted in the JSON

I'm using .Net 4.0.

Hopefully this is clear - please comment if not.

Comment: Are you able to change the json? I don't think what you want is possible without changes to the json.

Comment: The JSON is returned via an external service.  I guess I could manipulate the string prior to deserialization, but it is a huge string (there are thousands of DataItem, I have shortened the sample for clarity).  Short answer - not really! I had hoped there was a way via attributes on the Series class.

Comment: I wouldn't manipulate the string - you'd be asking for trouble! See my answer

Answer (score 1):

Without being able to change the incoming json I think you will have to have both properties:

```
public List<List<Object>> Data { get; set; }
public List<DataItem> DataMapped { get; set; }
```

deserialize to your 'data' property and then have a mapping function that will map from `data` to `dataMapped`

e.g.

```
//deserialize here, then...
for (int i = 0; i < Data.Count; i++)
{
    DataMapped.Add(new DataItem() { Date = Data[i][0].ToString(), Value = int.Parse(Data[i][1].ToString()) });
}
```

There's no checking for expected values here so you might need to add that - e.g. that the inner list definitely contains 2 objects etc...

Comment: Thanks @Rick.  I'll upvote but not accept your answer (I'm still hoping there is an attribute based way to achieve this!).  I'd prefer not to iterate through all data again.

Comment: No worries - yes there might be but it's beyond me if there is - I'd be interested to see that too.

Comment: You could always make your DataTem have a `List<Object> Stuff` property and then make your Date and Value properties return Stuff[0] and Stuff[1]. I've updated my answer to show this approach

Comment: ah - yes I guess the data types won't match up properly! worth a shot

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the json especially

```
     "data" : [["20160715", 1214561], 
   ["20160708", 1216904], 
   ["20160701", 1219452], 
   ["20160624", 1221677], 
   ["20160617", 1225730], 
   ["20160610", 1226647], 
   ["20160603", 1227580]]
```

Data is an Array of Arrays, so the online generator that you used has correctly converted the json to `public List<List<Object>> data { get; set; }`.

However you can later map this to `public List<DataItem> data { get; set; }` by simply iterating over the `public List<List<Object>> data { get; set; }` and  creating a `DataItem` per inner List.

Comment: Thanks @PreetSingh.  I am aware of that but was hoping to do this as part of deserialization, on the assumption that the deserializer must be iterating already.

Comment: As you said, your serializer is out of bounds and so is  modifying the FromJsonString method, there is not much left in order to plugin a custom serializer, you can however plug in a MediaTypeFormatter if your app is a Web API app. But my point is if the incoming data is an Array of Arrays then why  to convert Array of Objects end of the day DataItem is also a data, tuple in this case.